# File copied to a tempfile.TemporaryDirectory not found?

Tags: python

I'm expecting to receive some solutions to a take-home assignment in the form of directories containing a script (e.g., `solution.py` or `solution.js`) which, when run in the same directory (with `python solution.py` or `node solution.js`) will read an `input.txt` in that directory and produce an `output.json`.

I would like to write 'unit tests' for such directories such that they effectively run different inputs (`input1.txt`, `input2.txt`, etc.). My approach to this is to create a temporary directory, copy the solution script to it, copy the relevant input file (renamed to `input.txt`), and run the script in the temporary directory. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import tempfile
import os
import shutil
import argparse
import subprocess
import time

# Name of the input and output file
INPUT_FILE = 'input.txt'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.json'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Run take-home assignment test script")
parser.add_argument('solutiondir')


def run_test(solutiondir, inputfile):
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        copy_input_file(inputfile, tempdir)

        maybe_run_python(solutiondir, tempdir)


def copy_input_file(inputfile, tempdir):
    shutil.copyfile(inputfile, os.path.join(tempdir, INPUT_FILE))


def maybe_run_python(solutiondir, tempdir):
    solutionpy = os.path.join(solutiondir, 'solution.py')
    if os.path.isfile(solutionpy):
        print("solution.py found. Running...")
        dst = os.path.join(tempdir, 'solution.py')
        shutil.copyfile(solutionpy, dst)
        tic = time.time()
        completed_process = subprocess.run(["python3", dst])
        toc = time.time()
        print(f"Process completed in {toc - tic}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_test(
        solutiondir=parser.parse_args().solutiondir,
        inputfile='test/inputs/input1.txt')
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── solutions
│   └── Test
│       └── solution.py
└── test
    ├── inputs
    │   └── input1.txt
    └── run_solution.py
```

The script above is `run_solution.py`, and I have a `Test/solution.py` which contains just one line:

```
open('input.txt')
```

However, if I try to run the script, I get an error that `input.txt` was not found:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:cleo-challenge kurtpeek$ python test/run_solution.py solutions/Test
solution.py found. Running...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/0p/jfjngh2x19dfyg2dpxnw7f2h0000gn/T/tmp02q4nmc8/solution.py", line 1, in <module>
    open('input.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'
Process completed in 0.02921915054321289.
```

What puzzles me, though, is that if I drop into the debugger just before `open('input.txt')`, I see that the temporary directory is at the start of the path:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:cleo-challenge kurtpeek$ python test/run_solution.py solutions/Test
solution.py found. Running...
> /var/folders/0p/jfjngh2x19dfyg2dpxnw7f2h0000gn/T/tmpguwf91h7/solution.py(2)<module>()
      1 import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
----> 2 open('input.txt')

ipdb> import sys
ipdb> sys.path
['', '/private/var/folders/0p/jfjngh2x19dfyg2dpxnw7f2h0000gn/T/tmpguwf91h7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/kurtpeek/.ipython']
ipdb>
```

Further, if I open up that directory, I do see an `input.txt` in it:

[image]

Is the 'effective' `sys.path` not the one that exists just before opening the file? Do I have to do `os.chdir()` or something? Why is it not finding the input file?

Comment: `sys.path` is the list of paths where Python will look for **modules** when importing. Python will look for your file in the current working directory, so yes, you will have to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert [Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille)'s comment to an answer, I got it to work by first doing `os.chdir(tempdir)` and then simply running `subprocess.run(["python3", "solution.py"])`.